# PFFacebookUtils is not resolved after upgrading parse cocoapod

Tags: ios, ios7, parse-platform, cocoapods, parsefacebookutils

I just updated the pod file on my project to increase parse version from 
`1.2.19` to `1.5.0`, now I'm getting compilation error for `PFFacebookUtils` class as the following

> Use of undeclared identifier 'PFFacebookUtils'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Parse has made Facebook utility separated from Parse framework. So I had to add cocoa pod for ParseFacebookUtils

`pod 'ParseFacebookUtils', '~> 1.5.0.1'`

then add the following line to the header:

`#import <ParseFacebookUtils/PFFacebookUtils.h>`

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion would be to import `ParseFacebookUtils/PFFacebookUtils.h` (inside of carrots of course) instead of `ParseFacebookUtils/ParseFacebookUtils.h`

I know its strange, but it worked for me.

Comment: Translation: carrots → carets → angle brackets.